# HTML/JS: Confused about method to create an image button

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I need to create a simple button made only of an image, and which will open a JQuery Dialog when the user clicks on it.

I am doing some reading and notice many solutions: `<button>`, `<image>` with a `<a>`, using CSS to modify a button background, etc...

This is confusing, what is the proper way to implement my image button?

Thanks.

**P.S.:** The button/image should be focussable. An operational JSFiddle example is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution after many struggles: http://jsfiddle.net/YRY8M/3/.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="image" tabindex="0" onclick="doSomething()" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/White_and_yellow_flower.JPG/320px-White_and_yellow_flower.JPG"
    />
    <br />
    <button tabindex="1">I am focussable too !!!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And some javascript:

```
function doSomething() {
  alert('Hello!'); 
}
```

Comment: Glad that you found the appropriate solution for you!
It seems that it is the same that i proposed as more suitable for you and since now none of the other comments is mentioning it, so if you wish you can accept my answer instead.

Answer (score 9):

The proper way largely depends on what the button will do if JavaScript is not available.

If you are going to submit a form then:

```
<button> <img src="..." alt="..."> </button>
```

If you are going to go to a URL then:

```
<a href="..."> <img src="..." alt="..."> </a>
```

If you are going to do absolutely nothing (generally not a good idea, you should follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), but acceptable if you only generate the button with JavaScript in the first place and the loss to the user is convenience rather then essential functionality):

```
<button type="button"> <img src="..." alt="..."> </button>
```

You then bind the JavaScript to either the form's submit event, or the button/anchor's click event and [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) so the form won't be submitted / the link won't be followed if the JavaScript executes successfully.

Comment: The button displays a modal box with an autocomplete. When closed, the selected value is displayed in a div and used to compute another value every second with a timer. So, which method should I use, because it does not fit any case mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: An operational JSFiddle would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Create a button and put `background-image` for it.
Checkout the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/siyakunde/Y38nz/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do in every case. There is no guideline that says "you should do it like this", but there are situations that some cases are more suitable than others.

For example according to [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/button#compatibilitysection) review, IE versions of 8 and below have some buggy behaviour regarding `<button>` tag when trying to use it as a submit button.

Ηowever the `<button>` has some new attributes added in HTML5 which you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) , ammong them is `autofocus` and other useful that will be supported by most modern major browsers.

In your case that you want to maintain the "focus" (i assume with tabbing support), if you use a single `<image>` as a button (with or without `<a>`), you will have to add some JS code to make the image focusable when the  appropriate tab is pressed. So you will have to write a bit more code to do the same thing.

There is one more solution which might be suitable for you, since you do not need to submit the form to server side. Using the `<input type="image"` type and defining the `src` attribute inside it, will be focusable and not require neither any JS code to run nor any difficult CSS. You can find more about it's syntax [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html)

So, it ends up to you to decide which one of all them to use. 
I would use the one that i find more flexible, easier for me to code, easily reusable and is supported by most of my target browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery as you own it...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #theBtn{
                margin: 20% auto 0;
                background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/White_and_yellow_flower.JPG/320px-White_and_yellow_flower.JPG');
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="theBtn"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#theBtn").click(function(){
                    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
                        $("#theBtn").fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside a `<button>` tag , put your image, and attach an click event to `<button>` to open the dialog on click.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svineet/cJWRk/)

Answer (score 2):

First thing, There is either an image or a button. But not both.
I would say, create an image and place your code in the onclick() function of that image.

```
 var img= $("#my-image-id");
    image.click(function() {
    // your code here
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this. The image will not be focusable (since images are not designed to be interactive controls). People using (for instance) a keyboard to navigate through the page (instead of a pointing device like a mouse) won't be able to navigate to the image and activate the control.

Answer (score 2):

As I know You can't change the look of the Safari buttons thats why I suggest to use `a` for the solution. Here is my simple code: http://jsfiddle.net/djgBK/1/

The basis is:

1. Take an `a` element put the link content to the left,
2. Then replace it with image that is actualy it's background. Becouse it's `a` element user can select it usin only `TAB` button.

What's more using an `a` elemet will let You to put `title` which will be displayed after hovering/entering over the button.