# How to make an image focussable?

Tags: javascript, image, focus

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140209/html-js-confused-about-method-to-create-an-image-button), someone is suggesting that an image can be made focussable? How can one achieve this?

**More information:**

In the other question, Quentin says:

```
 var img= $("#my-image-id");
    image.click(function() {
    // your code here
    }
```

> Don't do this. The image will not be focusable (since images are not
>   designed to be interactive controls). People using (for instance) a
>   keyboard to navigate through the page (instead of a pointing device
>   like a mouse) won't be able to navigate to the image and activate the
>   control.

Someone else says:

> In your case that you want to maintain the "focus" (i assume with
>   tabbing support), if you use a single  as a button (with or
>   without ), you will have to add some JS code to make the image
>   focusable when the appropriate tab is pressed. So you will have to
>   write a bit more code to do the same thing.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but use tabindex="0" to make it highlighted (onfocus) when you are using tab to navigate.
Can you please write some more about what you mean..

Comment: did you mean http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: I am not sure myself what they meant. I have updated the question with more information. They mention javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an image (or any element) focusable, just add a `tabindex` attribute.

```
<img src="myimage.png" tabindex="1" />
```

But note that there is no need for any special treatment just to make an image respond to `click` events.

Answer (score 1):

You can just place an `img` inside a `button`.

So, the focus will reach the button, click event can be binded to the button, but it will look exactly like the image has focus.